# Asp.Net Mvc Linq issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I know my problem is really basic. If I write `/api/category/1`, I wanna list all Tales with the `categoryId==1`. I wrote this code, but it gives an error.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Tale> GetAllTalesByCategory(int id)
{
    var tales = TaleService.FindAllTale().Select(x => new Tale
    {
        TaleId = x.TaleId,
        TaleName = x.TaleName,
        Content = x.Content,
        VoicePath = x.VoicePath
    }).Where(x => new Tale
    {
        x.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryId).First() == id                    
    });
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error   1   Cannot initialize type 'MasalYuvasi.Entities.Tale' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' D:\MvcProject\MasalYuvasi\MasalYuvasi\Controllers\DenemeController.cs   33  13  MasalYuvasi
```

**Models:**

```
public class Tale
{
    public int TaleId { get; set; }
    public string TaleName { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string VoicePath { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public Tale()
    {
        this.Categories = new List<Category>();
    }   
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tale> Tales { get; set; }
    public Category()
    {
        this.Tales = new List<Tale>();
    }
}
```

Comment: See "[Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx#sectionToggle1)"

Comment: What does your `FindAllTale()` return?

Comment: IEnumerable<Tale> is return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code is using a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx#sectionToggle1) here:

```
new Tale
{
    x.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryId).First() == id                    
}
```

I'm not sure what this code is supposed to be doing, but as `x.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryId).First() == id` will return a bool, I don't think this is doing what you want it to.

---

Based on your comment:

> I want to list in the category of tales. Forexample I have 2 tales in CategoryId is 1. If I write "/api/category/1" ı want to list this 2 tales.

I think you are looking for something simpler than what you've got. You want to select Tales (represented by `x`) where *Any* of the categories have a CategoryId of `id`:

```
.Where(x => x.Categories.Any(c => c.CategoryId == id ));
```

Note that you can append `.ToList()` to the end of the where clause, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20551231/211627) by pjobs, but this may have a subtle effect on the behavior of your application. For more detail, see [LINQ and Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

Comment: I want to list in the category of tales. Forexample I have 2 tales in CategoryId is 1. If I write "/api/category/1" ı want to list this 2 tales.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now I didn't take any error but return just like that "[]" Can u check pls my table image http://postimg.org/image/bb7t90vqr/ and if I need to say I create TalesCategory table with modelBuilder.

Comment: @BerdaN - I do not have access to that website (blocked by corporate filter) and your original question has been (apparently) answered. If you have a new question, please create a new post.

Comment: @BerdaN - Keep in mind that you should spend some time researching the question yourself before posting it. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service and many users will take issue with a cascade of questions, one bug after another, without any evidence that you've attempted to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: I think ı didnt explain. I said return just it "[]" but I expect return like "[{"TaleId":2,"TaleName":"dasd","Content":"saddasdaaaaaa","VoicePath":"asdasdas"] data.

Comment: Your question was about an error. The error has been fixed. Now it appears that there is a problem with your database architecture. This is a different issue and one that is almost impossible to diagnose through the messageboard format. I'd need to sit at your PC and use the Visual Studio debugger to see where the gap is. Maybe you aren't loading your data properly (the Categories property is empty) or maybe you are looking for a category that doesn't exist. I don't know... you need to look at your code and try to understand what's going on.

Comment: @BerdaN - If, after looking at it some more, you have a grasp of the problem but need more help, feel free to post another question.

Comment: I agree with u. I try to understand my code and problem. But my first time with mvc and EF Code First. So after I changed the platform from winform to mvc I have some space in my mind actually a lot of. Thanks for answer and advice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Tale> GetAllTalesByCategory(int id)
{
    var tales = TaleService.FindAllTale().Select(x => new Tale
    {
        TaleId = x.TaleId,
        TaleName = x.TaleName,
        Content = x.Content,
        VoicePath = x.VoicePath
    }).Where(x => x.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryId).First() == id).ToList();
}
```

Fixed the where condition, and added `.ToList()`.

Comment: You should add that `ToList()` will change the behavior of the program by causing the query to execute immediately rather than the deferred execution of the Where clause object (which is still an `IEnumerable<Tale>`).

Comment: I take this error "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code"